# Somar Coluna em SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou trabalhando em um sistema que preciso realizar uma soma que será feita em uma *view* do SQL Server. Em C# eu sei como resolver isso. Gostaria de resolver utilizando SQL.

> ```
> ColA    ColB
> 200911  1634,50
> 200911  558,29
> 200911  2446,66
> 200911  2860,90
> 200911  37905,01
> 200911  1238,11
> 200912  1634,50
> 200912  129191,82
> 200912  107644,42
> 200912  212634,97
> 200912  214817,55
> 200912  18754,56
> 200912  63911,39
> 200912  61991,81
> 201001  148,53
> 201001  17946,07
> 201001  1181,59
> 201001  108018,78
> 201001  3287,28
> 201001  191,17
> 201001  305,94
> ```

O Resultado que preciso chegar é este :

> ```
> ColA    ColB
> 200911  46643,47
> 200912  810581,018
> 201001  131079,361
> ```

Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Qual é o tipo de dado da coluna ColB?

Answer (score 8):

Utilize um `GROUP BY` juntamente com o `SUM()`

```
SELECT ColA, SUM(ColB)
FROM tabela
GROUP BY ColA;
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado !!

Comment: @AndreTovar caso a resposta tenha solucionado seu problema, marque ela como respondida. Faça um [tour] e saiba mais a respeito.